# Tooltip issue with a D3 Choropeth Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am unable to display my data in the tooltip of my map, the following code returns an "undefined". However, I am able to see my rates in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "data/provincesCanada.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "data/data.csv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate);
    console.log(d.rate) })
    .await(ready);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Province</strong> : " + d.rate";
  })
  svg.call(tip);
```

The full code is here : http://bl.ocks.org/fdaudens/41a1fa381783ecd8d9ef

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you share a more complete version of your code? like a jsfiddle or similar thing...

Comment: Sure! The full gist is here: http://bl.ocks.org/fdaudens/41a1fa381783ecd8d9ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you face is that the tooltip is attached to the provinces data, and not to the rates csv file's data.

So the variable `d` inside the `.html` function does not contain the content you are expecting. The following should work:

```
.html(function(d) {
  return "<strong>Province</strong> : " + rateById.get(d.id);
})
```

You can see it in action in this [fork of your gist](http://bl.ocks.org/mef/aebc4d4ce57cd26a8d8f).

Comment: Wonderful, it works like a charm! I need to better understand the rateById. Thank you very much.